# Extjs - Best way to iterate through displayed records in a buffered store

Tags: javascript, extjs

So, I'm upgrading from **EXT 4.1.1a to 4.2.2** and have come across a problem with buffered stores. In 4.1.1a I could use `store.each` to iterate through the currently displayed store records, but in 4.2.2 I simply get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Basically inside the store object the `data` property does not have an `items` property anymore, and the `each` method uses the `length` property of the `items`, hence the error. Instead the items in the store seem to reside in `data.map`. I could loop through `data.map` but it seems there should be a better way. The docs only mention store.each as the way to do this even though this seems to fail for buffered stores.

I'm iterating through the store on the `refresh` listener attached to the grids view.

Any help with this would be much appreciated

Answer (score 7):

Apparently they think you can't iterate over the store because it has "sparse" data, but that is not true. Currently, what you could do is the following.

```
if(store.buffered) {
    // forEach is private and part of the private PageMap
    store.data.forEach(function(record, recordIdx) {
        /* Do stuff with the record here */
    }, this);
} else {
    store.each(function(record) {
        /* Do the same stuff I guess */
    }, this);
}
```

**IMPORTANT**

*Take care that can change the structure of the store in the future which will surely brake your code.*

Additionally, I strongly believe that if proper design patterns were used, `each` had to take care of the looping without caring about the structure.

**OPTIMIZATION**

What I usually do, when I initialize the store is the following:

```
if(store.buffered) {
    store.iterate = store.data.forEach;
} else {
    store.iterate = store.each;
}
```

Then you could just use it like this:

`store.iterate(fn, scope);`

This is not the best decision but simplifies writing a lot of *if*-statements